# Using value of cell to search text of another sheet and highlight cell if match is found

Tags: microsoft-excel, comparison

Scenario is a workbook with two sheets. I need a way for cells on sheet 2 to search sheet 1 and highlight themselves if they find any text on sheet 1 that matches.

So cell `sheet2!a2` with value of `apple` searches `sheet1`. It finds `apple` somewhere on `sheet1` and now `sheet2!a2` is highlighted green. Keep in mind, `apple` may only be part of the cells in `sheet1`.

Running excel 2012. Any ideas?

The problem with a conditional format that I can setup, even using the countif function, is that the cells have to be completely equal. Meaning if i use the above example. If the cell on sheet2 says "apple" but the cell on sheet1 says"apple-1" the conditional formatting will not work.

How can I adjust the formula to look for the same text within the cell and highlight and not actually look for a exact matching cell?

Comment: Sounds like a job for conditional formatting.

Comment: haha yup! But I am having a hard time adjusting it to how i need it to.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the values are in col A for both sheets, add this conditional formatting rule using a formula to sheet2 col A:

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!$A:$A,A1)>=1
```

Comment: Thank you, the issue is though, this type of function requires the cells to be copies of each other. What I am trying to see is if there is a function that will look for the same text in a cell that may not match exactly. So the cell that says "apple" would highlight if it found a cell that said "apple123"

Comment: `=COUNTIF(Sheet1!A1,"*"&A1&"*")`

Comment: Kyle's solution is correct. Sorry, I stopped reading at "any ideas". Wildcards like * and ? (single character) are accepted in Excel formulas.

Comment: Learn something new everyday. I swear, all the web searching in the world and I couldn't find something so simple. Thanks all!